# Django 1.6 admin .preserve_filters not working with MPTT 0.6 admin.MPTTModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-mptt, django-1.6, mptt

All,

I have a django 1.6 admin page and I would like to use MPTT but whenever I use mptt.admin.MPTTModelAdmin, preserve_filters no longer works.  If I use the standard django ModelAdmin, then preserve_filters works great.  Any ideas why the MPTTModelAdmin breaks preserve_filters?

For Example:

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    preserve_filters = True

 # Works GREAT and saves the filter when editing/saving a "Group" object
```

This does not work.

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.MPTTModelAdmin):
    preserve_filters = True
```

Does not preserve any list_filter choices after saving/editing a "Group" object.

Thanks for any and all help.